# Different text label size in iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, uilabel

I have an App in swift for iPad and iPhone.

I have a tableview, in each row there is a text. I want to change the size of the text depends of the device.

For example:

- iPhone 5s size = 14
- iPhone 6s size = 18
- iPad = 24

I have a lot of labels in the App so I don't want to check the device and set the size in code. There is a way to do in the Interface Builder?

How can I solve?

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this is by checking the device's screen size using `self.view.frame.height`. This will return a `CGFloat` that we can use in a conditional, inside of which we can alter our `UILabel`'s font name and size.

```
// Check Device Size //
let screenSize = self.view.frame.height
if screenSize <= 740.0 {
    // iPhones //
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14.0)
} else  {
    // iPads //
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 24.0)
}
```

Another, *slightly better* way to accomplish this same thing would be to set specific layouts for different size classes in `Storyboard`. To set up your application for all iPhones in landscape or portrait layout, you would want to change your size class to `Compact Width`. For all iPads in landscape or portrait, you would use `Regular Width | Regular Height`.

**EDIT:** Updated code example to simply separate between iPad and IPhone screen sizes.

Comment: I just want to separate between iPhone and iPad

Answer (score 1):

I found a good solution to this case:

Duplicate the storyboard and have one to iPhones and another one to iPads.
In the different storyboards I just need to set the size of the text.

It solved my problem.

Comment: While this may end up working in the end, it adds extra weight and confusion to your project. Take a look at the use of Size Classes and installing and uninstalling certain views per Size Class.

Answer (score 0):

Select your text field/label in your storyboard. In the attributes inspector you will see a small '+' to the left of the font selector. This will allow you to choose size-class specific stuff for your text.

Size classes were added to iOS 8 when Apple introduced Universal Storyboards which let you design for both iPad and iPhone with the same Storyboard file. At the bottom of the Storyboard design window you'll see the (default) 'w Any h Any' button. This gives you access to combinations of the compact and regular size classes. These available combinations let you implement design, say for only the iPhone in landscape, or maybe the iPad in both orientations. You have full control.

For your font related question, you access the size-class control through the '+' sign I mentioned above.

Comment: I tried but then text is always the same (14 px) I tried all the combination.
What is the combination to iPad, and to iPhone??

Comment: This doesn't separate out the difference between an iPhone 5s and an iPhone 6s.

Comment: It separate out between iPad and iPhone?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what size classes are for.